# How to thread a sequence of actions through multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

*I am exploring a problem which is likely a special case of a problem class, but I don't know the problem class nor the appropriate terminology, so I have to resort to desribing the problem using ad-hoc vocabulary. I'll rephrase once I know the right terminology.*

I have a bunch of singletons `A`, `B`, `C`. The singletons are:

- Unrelated. There are no constraints like "you must access B before you can do X with C" or similar.
- Not thread-safe.

The system accepts tasks to be processed in parallel as far as possible.
Each task consists of a sequence of actions, each action to be executed using one of the singletons. Different tasks may access different singleton in different order, and tasks may contain loops of actions.

Pseudocode:

```java
void myTask(in1, in2, ...) {
    doWithA(() -> {
       // use in1, in2, ...
       // inspect and/or update A
       // set up outputs to be used as inputs for the next action:
       outA1 = ...
       outA2 = ...
       ...
    });
    doWithB(() -> {
       // use outA1, outA2, ...
       // inspect and/or update B
       // set up outputs to be used as inputs for the next action:
       outB1 = ...
       outB2 = ...
       ...
    });
    // Tasks may touch singletons repeatedly, in any order
    doWithA(() -> {
       // outB1, outB2, ..., inspect/modify A, set up outputs
       outAx1 = ...
       outAx2 = ...
       ...
    });
    // Tasks may have loops:
    while (conditionInC(() -> ...) {
        doWithC(() -> ...);
        doWithD(() -> ...);
    }
    // I am aware that a loop like this can cause a livelock.
    // That's an aspect for another question, on another day.
}
```

There are multiple tasks like `myTask` above.
Tasks to be executed are wrapped in a closure and scheduled to a `ThreadPoolExecutor` (or something similar).

Approaches I considered:

1. Have singletons `LockA`, `LockB`, ...
   Each `doWithX` is merely a `synchronized(X)` block.
   `OutXn` are local variables of `myTask`.
   *Problem*: One of the singletons is Swing, and I can't move the EDT into a thread that I manage.
2. As above. Solve the Swing problem from approach (1) by coding `doWithSwing(){...}` as `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(() -> {...}`.
   *Problem*: `invokeAndWait` is generally considered prone to deadlock. How do I find out if I am into this kind of trouble with the pattern above?
3. Have threads `threadA`, `threadB`, ..., each of them "owning" one of the singletons (Swing already has this, it is the EDT).
   `doWithX` schedules the block as a `Runnable` on `threadX`.
   `outXn` are set up as `Future<...> outXn = new SettableFuture<>()`, the assignments become `outXn.set(...)`.
   *Problem*: I couldn't find anything like `SettableFuture` in the JDK; all ways to create a `Future`that I could find were somehow tied to a `ThreadPool`. Maybe I am looking at the wrong top-level interface and `Future` is a red herring?

With of these approaches would be best?
Is there a superior approach that I didn't consider?

Comment: Quote: _"Solve the Swing problem_" I don't think you mentioned what the swing problem is. Also it is not clear to me what is the "_sequence of actions_" you want to synchronize.

Comment: @akuzminykh Done - thanks for the feedback, hopefully it's clearer now. Feel free to ask more if anything is still unclear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know the problem class nor the appropriate terminology

I'd probably just refer to the problem class as *concurrent task orchestration*.

There's a lot of things to consider when identifying the right approach. If you provide some more details, I'll try to update my answer with more color.

> There are no constraints like "you must access B before you can do X with C" or similar.

This is generally a good thing. A very common cause of deadlocks is different threads acquiring the same locks in differing orders. E.g., thread 1 locks A then B while thread 2 owns the lock B and is waiting to acquire A. Designing the solution such that this situation does not occur is very important.

> I couldn't find anything like `SettableFuture` in the JDK

Take a look at `java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture<T>` - this is probably what you want here. It exposes a blocking `get()` as well as a number of asynchronous completion callbacks such as `thenAccept(Consumer<? super T>)`.

> `invokeAndWait` is generally considered prone to deadlock

It depends. If your calling thread isn't holding any locks that are going to be necessary for the execution of the `Runnable` you're submitting, you're probably okay. That said, if you can base your orchestration on asynchronous callbacks, you can instead use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)` - this will submit the execution of your `Runnable` on the Swing event loop without blocking the calling thread.

I would probably avoid creating a thread per singleton. Each running thread contributes some overhead and it's better to decouple the number of threads from your business logic. This will allow you to tune the software to different physical machines based on the number of cores, for example.

It sounds like you need each `runWithX(...)` method to be *atomic*. In other words, once one thread has begun accessing X, another thread cannot do so until the first thread is finished with its task step. If this is the case, then creating a lock object per singleton and insuring *serial* (rather than *parallel*) access is the right way to go. You can achieve this by wrapping the execution of closures that get submitted in your `runWithX(...)` methods in a `synchronized` Java code block. The code within the block is also referred to as the *critical section* or *monitor region*.

Another thing to consider is *thread contention* and order of execution. If two tasks both require access to X and task 1 gets submitted before task 2, is it a requirement that task 1's access to X occurs before task 2's? A requirement like that can complicate the design quite a bit and I would probably recommend a different approach than outlined above.

> Is there a superior approach that I didn't consider?

These days there are frameworks out there for solving these types of problems. I'm specifically thinking of reactive streams and [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava). While it is a very powerful framework, it also comes with a very steep learning curve. A lot of analysis and consideration should be done before adopting such a technology within an organization.

---

**Update:**

Based on your feedback, I think a `CompletableFuture`-based approach probably makes the most sense.

I'd create a helper class to orchestrate task step execution:

```
class TaskHelper
{
    private final Object lockA;
    private final Object lockB;
    private final Object lockC;

    private final Executor poolExecutor;
    private final Executor swingExecutor;

    public TaskHelper()
    {
        poolExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 2 );
        swingExecutor = SwingUtilities::invokeLater;

        lockA = new Object();
        lockB = new Object();
        lockC = new Object();
    }

    public <T> CompletableFuture<T> doWithA( Supplier<T> taskStep )
    {
        return doWith( lockA, poolExecutor, taskStep );
    }

    public <T> CompletableFuture<T> doWithB( Supplier<T> taskStep )
    {
        return doWith( lockB, poolExecutor, taskStep );
    }

    public <T> CompletableFuture<T> doWithC( Supplier<T> taskStep )
    {
        return doWith( lockC, swingExecutor, taskStep );
    }

    private <T> CompletableFuture<T> doWith( Object lock, Executor executor, Supplier<T> taskStep )
    {
        CompletableFuture<T> future = new CompletableFuture<>();

        Runnable serialTaskStep = () -> {

            T result;

            synchronized ( lock ) {
                result = taskStep.get();
            }

            future.complete( result );
        };

        executor.execute( serialTaskStep );
        return future;
    }
}
```

In my example above `withA` and `withB` get scheduled on a shared thread pool while `withC` is always executed on the Swing thread. The Swing `Executor` is already going to be serial in nature, so the lock is really optional there.

For creating actual tasks, I'd recommend creating an object for each task. This allows you to supply callbacks as method references, resulting in cleaner code and avoiding callback hell:

[image: callback hell]

This example computes the square of a provided number on a background thread pool and then displays the results on the Swing thread:

```
class SampleTask
{
    private final TaskHelper helper;
    private final String id;
    private final int startingValue;

    public SampleTask( TaskHelper helper, String id, int startingValue )
    {
        this.helper = helper;
        this.id = id;
        this.startingValue = startingValue;
    }

    private void start()
    {
        helper.doWithB( () -> {

            int square = startingValue * startingValue;
            return String.format( "computed-thread: %s computed-square: %d",
                    Thread.currentThread().getName(), square );
        } )
        .thenAccept( this::step2 );
    }

    private void step2( String result )
    {
        helper.doWithC( () -> {

            String message = String.format( "current-thread: %s task: %s result: %s",
                    Thread.currentThread().getName(), id, result );

            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog( null, message );
            return null;
        } );
    }
}

@Test
public void testConcurrent() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException
{
    TaskHelper helper = new TaskHelper();

    new SampleTask( helper, "task1", 5 ).start();
    new SampleTask( helper, "task2", 7 ).start();

    Thread.sleep( 60000 );
}
```

---

**Update 2:**

If you want to avoid callback hell while also avoiding the need to create an object per task, perhaps you should take a serious look at reactive streams after all.

Take a look at the "getting started" page for RxJava:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/How-To-Use-RxJava

For reference here's how the same example above would look in Rx (I'm removing the concept of task ID for simplicity):

```
@Test
public void testConcurrentRx() throws InterruptedException
{
    Scheduler swingScheduler = Schedulers.from( SwingUtilities::invokeLater );
    Subject<Integer> inputSubject = PublishSubject.create();

    inputSubject
        .flatMap( input -> Observable.just( input )
                .subscribeOn( Schedulers.computation() )
                .map( this::computeSquare ))
        .observeOn( swingScheduler )
        .subscribe( this::displayResult );

    inputSubject.onNext( 5 );
    inputSubject.onNext( 7 );
    Thread.sleep( 60000 );
}

private String computeSquare( int input )
{
    int square = input * input;
    return String.format( "computed-thread: %s computed-square: %d",
            Thread.currentThread().getName(), square );
}

private void displayResult( String result )
{
    String message = String.format( "current-thread: %s result: %s",
            Thread.currentThread().getName(), result );

    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog( null, message );
}
```

Comment: Thread contention is a non-issue here. If it isn't thread-safe, you have to serialize no matter what. I forgot to mention it's a GUI application, so the multithreading is for cutting down the latency, not for increasing throughput (new insight here: that this is a core difference in the software design between desktop and server applications).

Comment: Within a task, actions have to happen in order. Otherwise, it's meh... we don't care much, all activity is either initiated from the GUI or from the server delivering new data (which never interferes with user input, that's a pretty fortunate situation I guess). We _might_ have race conditions if multiple tasks are submitted near-simultaneously, where the actions get interleaved and access the same singletons. Still, there's no race condition at the logical level, all data is either fully under user control or fully under server control, so this should be a non-issue.

Comment: @toolforger I threw together an example with some building blocks on how to accomplish this using `CompletableFuture` based on your feedback. I think you can go further and add syntactical sugar around the definition of tasks, but it will probably require something like annotation processing and/or code generation.

Comment: Yep, callback hell is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. However, I want to avoid having to name each object, since they's essentially just "first do this then that" actions and have no notable semantics on their own (and refactoring/maintenance may change what each of them is doing at the drop of a hat). I'll think a bit more about this aspect. Your feedback is still very much appreciated!

Comment: @toolforger gotcha. Added another update based on feedback. Perhaps something like Rx is better suited for your needs.

Comment: thanks, I just took a slightly closer look at Rx - this seems intriguing, I'll pursue adding that to our toolbox of cool techniques.

Comment: This Rx stuff sounds fascinating, btw. I can't really judge it without having tried it, but it's a very interesting approach that I wish I had seen 10 years ago.

Comment: @toolforger I think the technology was in its infancy 10 years ago, it's gained traction in the last 5 years or so. I'm definitely fascinated by it. My only concern with it after using for about 6 months is the steep learning curve. But man.. once you wrap your head around it, it's game-changer for asynchronous code.

Comment: hmm... I don't find it hard to grasp. OTOH I had quite the journey with thoroughly understanding all of Pascal/C, Prolog, Lisp, Smalltalk, Eiffel, Haskell, deciphered my first Pattern before even knowing what a Pattern is; maybe I just have a head start with "getting into" new paradigms.